# .Net - Error while creating lambda from expression

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've a Generic method the following class to help me with some expression problems.

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class ExpressionHelper { 
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> All<T>()
    {
        return e => true;
    }
    public static ParameterExpression ParameterExpression<T>(string parameterName="e")
    {
        return Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), parameterName);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateLambdaExpression<T>(Expression bodyExpression, ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(bodyExpression , parameterExpression);
    }
}
```

For example, I've a class Person, that I use in T generics

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
}
```

Together with it here is my testing program class

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var persons = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person {Name = "John"},
                new Person {Name = "Doe"},
                new Person {Name = "Mark"},
                new Person {Name = "Carl"},
            };
            var parameterExpression = ExpressionHelper.ParameterExpression<Person>();
            var bodyExpression = ExpressionHelper.All<Person>();
            var lambdaExpression = ExpressionHelper.CreateLambdaExpression<Person>(bodyExpression, parameterExpression);
            var filterdPersons = persons.Where(lambdaExpression.Compile());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Error that I'm experiencing:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[Person,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, String paramName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
   at ExpressionHelper.CreateLambdaExpression[T](Expression bodyExpression, ParameterExpression parameterExpression) in E:\_Development\_repos\codescovery\github\pocs\src\c#\console\FilPocs.CSharp.Console.FilterBuilder\ExpressionHelper.cs:line 14
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\_Development\_repos\codescovery\github\pocs\src\c#\console\FilPocs.CSharp.Console.FilterBuilder\Program.cs:line 18
```

Comment: Your error is fixed by passing the body of the expression:  `ExpressionHelper.CreateLambdaExpression<Person>(bodyExpression.Body, parameterExpression)`.  This, however, will not work with bodies using parameters.

Comment: What I would like to know is:  Why do you want the code to do this?  Is it an experiment?  Because the end result is the exact expression you started with.

Comment: I'm trying to create dymically queries based on a object. 
I've done everything, the main problem was that i need to create a default case, that would return  all

Comment: Well, like I said, if youdo `bodyExpression.Body` you can get your sample to run.  However, the result of the `Compile()` call is the exact delegate you started with, so basically no need to go through all this.  The `All()` call is giving you exactly what you need.

Comment: I'll try to use it, the other way I figure out to make it work was:
Change the return type of `All()` function to `Expression` only,  with a return of `Expression.Constant(true)`

Answer (score 0):

In your **CreateLambdaExpression** method, expression `Expression.Lambda(bodyExpression, parameterExpression)` return type is **Func<Person,Func<Person,bool>>** not **Func<Person,bool>**, so it will throw an exception.

Maybe you can create expression like this:

```
var param = ParameterExpression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "e");
var name = Expression.Property(param, "Name");
var body = Expression.Equal(name, Expression.Constant("Mark"));
var expression = (Expression<Func<Person, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(body, param);
var filter = persons.Where(expression.Compile()).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense. body expression is an expression e => True of type Expression<Func<Person, bool>>